# ASP.NET 4.0 Ajax Progress Bar Options

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I can't believe how many articles I have read and example code I've tried to understand, with no success in accomplishing what I need to do. Hopefully someone can help me out by providing some example code or pointing me to another resource.

I am working in ASP.NET 4.0, C# using VS 2012 Express. The project is a web site. I have a UI page that contains checkbox controls and dropdowns for a user to set preferences. At the bottom of the page is a checkbox for the user to agree to some terms and conditions and an image button they click to get the results based on their preferences. This all works and so does the results page.

The problem is that the results page takes as much as 90 seconds to complete. I can't just leave the user with a "Loading..." on the status bar of their browser. So what I am wanting is:

User clicks to get results
Results page loads immediately
Once results page has loaded, a call is made to server that begins the 90 second process.
User is provided a status display of the progress.
Once process completes, a link is presented for them to view their results.

I see many examples with varied approaches. Most of them require the user to click a button to begin the process. I don't want the user to have to click another button - I just want the process to begin when the results page is finished loading.

Additionally, I'm looking for an idea of how to code the client page to make calls to the server to obtain the status of the process. Preferably a percentage value and a text message for each step of the process. Ie:

25%
Compressing files...

I've seen some Web Method examples, but I don't think I've seen a single one that demonstrates beginning the process initially without having to click a button to invoke it initially. I considered putting the Javascript call in the , but it is contained in a Master.Master that is used by many other pages.

Does anyone know of any code examples that might help me accomplish this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a really nice solution from EssentialObjects.com. Their progress bar control is free, although I needed their CallBack custom control to do what I wanted - the CallBack control is not free.

Hope this helps someone else out!